# c++/cli error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'

Tags: c++-cli

High, guys! Sorry to ask you this question, but I can´t find what causes the error. Also, I'm new at Visual C++/CLI, so I know my code could use some polishing.
In short, what I'm trying to do is capture data from a form to build a class.
I'd appreciate any help. THANKS IN ADVANCE.

My code:

```
// Form4A.h
#pragma once
# include "Tutors.h"
namespace SisPro
{
  //.... more code

  public ref class Form4A : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
  {
    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

    //.... more code

    #pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
      String ^ m1  = comboBox14->SelectedItem->ToString();
      String ^ m2  = comboBox19->SelectedItem->ToString();
      String ^ m3  = comboBox20->SelectedItem->ToString();
      Tutors.add_tutor(m1, m2, m3);// ERROR C2143
    }
  };
}
```

SOMWHERE ELSE:

```
//Tutors.h
using namespace System;
public ref class Tutors
{
  public:
     Tutors();
     void add_tutor(String ^ m1, String ^ m2, String ^ m3)
  private:
     String ^ ID;
     String ^ LASTNAME;
     String ^ NAME;
};

// tutors.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Tutores.h"
Tutors::Tutors()
{
    ID       = "";
    LASTNAME = "";
    NAME     = "";
}
void Tutors::add_tutor(String ^ m1, String ^ m2, String ^ m3)
{
   ID       = m1;
   LASTNAME = m2;
   NAME     = m3;
   return;
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `add_tutor` without an instance of `Tutors`. The implementation of `add_tutor` makes no sense, as well as the class `Tutors` itself: it represents a single tutor, nor multiple ones as its pluralized name suggests. You need to have a collection of tutors somewhere if you'd like to implement `add_tutor` correctly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @svick I did not provide enough info to fix the issue, so I posted it as a comment. I hope this comment would provide more info to the OP to update his question, then I'd post something more comprehensive.

Comment: Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach to what I want to do, but neither books nor experts ever tell you how to tackle the simple things. All they come up with is the "Hello World!" example. SORRY I ASKED!

Comment: You can't learn the difference between a class and an object from a Hello World program.  Experts are pretty powerless to find a common language to explain a problem if there is no common ground.  You really do need to learn the basics of OOP from a book or a school.

Answer (score 0):

Add field Tutors in class Form4A. And add field initialization in constructor.

```
public ref class Form4A : public System::Windows::Forms::Form 
{ 
  #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code 

  //.... more code 

  Form4A()
  {
    //..

    this->Tutors = gcnew Tutors();
  }


  #pragma endregion 

  Tutors^ Tutors;

  private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
  { 
    String ^ m1  = comboBox14->SelectedItem->ToString(); 
    String ^ m2  = comboBox19->SelectedItem->ToString(); 
    String ^ m3  = comboBox20->SelectedItem->ToString(); 
    Tutors.add_tutor(m1, m2, m3);// ERROR C2143 
  } 
};
```